# lldb issue on mac with debugging a basic c program

Tags: lldb

I am trying to learn how to use a debugger and I am having some difficulty getting lldb to work properly.  In particular, I was trying to follow along with the code [the lldb wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLDB_(debugger)) for starters, and after attempting to run the debugger with `lldb run` I obtained the following error:

```
(lldb) target create "./example"
Current executable set to '/Users/me/Desktop/c/old/example' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
Process 69451 launched: '/Users/me/Desktop/c/old/example' (x86_64)
Process 69451 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xffffff90)
    frame #0: 0x00007ff80f9066b2 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strlen + 18
libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strlen:
->  0x7ff80f9066b2 <+18>: pcmpeqb (%rdi), %xmm0
    0x7ff80f9066b6 <+22>: pmovmskb %xmm0, %esi
    0x7ff80f9066ba <+26>: andq   $0xf, %rcx
    0x7ff80f9066be <+30>: orq    $-0x1, %rax
Target 0: (example) stopped.
(lldb)
```

I searched around online and I could not seem to find what this was all about.  I would try to use gdb instead, but it looks like a bit of a mess to set up on mac with permissions and all.  Any thoughts on what this issue is?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a debugger error, lldb is reporting that your program crashed in the _platform_strlen function because of a bad memory access (that's what `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means).  From the crash message, the address you were trying to access was `0xffffff90`.

The frame you stopped in is from a system library, so all the debugger can show you is the disassembly of the function.  It is interesting (for people who can read disassembly).  `(%rdi)` means "fetch the memory at the address held in the register `rdi`.  That's an argument passing register, so presumably one of the arguments to strlen was bogus.  That makes sense with the crash reason.

The next thing to do is to issue the `bt` command to see the full stack trace for the crash.  Then use the `frame select` - short alias `f` - command to choose the last stack frame with your code.  Presumably the PC in that frame will be a call to `strlen`, and your code is passing a bad pointer to strlen.  You can use the `v <varname>` command to see the variable you passed in to verify that.